# estimating variance using only data at the tails without resorting to Gibbs sampling

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, estimation, dataset, missing-data

Suppose we know that the population size is $n=1,000$ but for whatever reason, we only have the bottom $n_1=100$ observations and the top $n_2 = 200$ observations. Furthermore, suppose we know the data $X_i \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^2)$. Basically, we are missing the middle $700$ observations but would like to estimate the variance $\sigma^2$.

Normally, I would sample the missing observations from a truncated Normal as part of a simple Normal-Inverse Gamma model. But suppose we can't do that. It seems to me that because we know the bounds of the observations we should have an analytical solution or at least some frequentist solution. Ideas?

Comment: Gene, please let me know whether the suggested solution is satisfactory for your purposes. I am curious to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an analytical solution:

If the data $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, then we expect that
$$
\hat{F}_n(x)\approx F(x),
$$
where $\hat{F}_n$ is the empirical CDF and $F$ is the true normal CDF,
$$
F(x)=\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. Let $x_{(1)},\ldots,x_{(n)}$ be the order statistics. We know the first 100 and last 200 of them. By definition of the empirical CDF,
$$
\hat{F}_n(x_{(k)})=\frac{k}{n}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{x_{(k)}}{\sigma}\right)\approx\frac{k}{n}.
$$
There is a little technical problem with this approximation for $k=n$ (the argument of $\Phi$ becomes infinite). The standard remedy is to replace $\frac{k}{n}$ with $\frac{k}{n+1}$:
$$
\Phi\left(\frac{x_{(k)}}{\sigma}\right)\approx\frac{k}{n+1},
$$
which for large $n$ (as in our case) works well. The above approximation gives an estimate for $\sigma$:
$$
\sigma\approx\frac{x_{(k)}}{\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)}.
$$
Since we know $m=n_1+n_2=300$ order statistics, we have $m$ estimates for $\sigma$. To cook up one estimate, we can take the average of them:
$$
\sigma\approx \frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n_1}\frac{x_{(k)}}{\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)}+\sum_{k=n-n_2+1}^n\frac{x_{(k)}}{\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)}\right).
$$

Comment: It seems there should be a better way than (equally) averaging these 300 estimates.

Comment: Maybe, but this would be only minor improvements. I checked with simulation: my solution works pretty well.

Comment: @Kostia, thanks for the solution. Would you mind modifying your empirical CDF to $\hat{F}_n(t) = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{x_i \leq k}$, I feel that that is the more canonical and generic version because it's robust to ties.

Comment: I think that the definition I used is more standard and natural. All modifications are for treating certain technical issues, which do not occur in this example. essentially for n=1000 both definitions a the same for all practical purposes :) So let me leave my solution as is, but highlight your comment as the one that "adds something useful to the post."